# Fatal error during accessing frame of one viewcontroller in another viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

i have a chess board on my viewcontroller. i want to get the space of view controller, which chess board is not occupied.

in the following code i have mentioned three classes
1- view controller class
2- chess game class
3- chessBoard class

In chessBoard class when i am calling "getFrames" method. it is showing "fatal error" as "SPACE_FROM_TOP_EDGE" and "TILE_SIZE" are nil.

how to get  "SPACE_FROM_TOP_EDGE" and "TILE_SIZE" of "view controller" class in "chessBoard" class ?

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var SPACE_FROM_LEFT_EDGE: CGFloat!
    var SPACE_FROM_TOP_EDGE: CGFloat!
    var TILE_SIZE: CGFloat!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        TILE_SIZE = self.view.frame.size.width / 8

        SPACE_FROM_TOP_EDGE = self.view.frame.size.height - (self.view.frame.size.width / 2)


        chessPiece = []

        myChessGame = ChessGame.init(viewController: self)
    }




        class ChessGame {
        var theChessBoard: chessBoard
        init(viewController: ViewController) {
            theChessBoard = chessBoard.init(viewController: viewController)

        }
    }




    class chessBoard {

    var board: [[Piece]]
    var vc: ViewController
    var ROWS = 8
    var COLS = 8
    var whiteKing: King!
    var blackKing: King!

    static func getFrames(forRow row: Int, forColoumn col: Int) -> CGRect{

        let vc = ViewController()
        print(vc.SPACE_FROM_TOP_EDGE)
        print(vc.TILE_SIZE)
        let x =   (CGFloat(col) * 40.0)

        let y =  vc.SPACE_FROM_TOP_EDGE! + (CGFloat(row) * 40.0)


        return CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), size: CGSize(width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
    }
    init(viewController: ViewController) {
        vc = viewController
        let oneRowOfBoard = Array(repeating: Dummy(), count: COLS)
        board = Array(repeating: oneRowOfBoard, count: ROWS)

         board[row][col] = Rook(frame: chessBoard.getFrames(forRow: row, forColoumn: col), color: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), vc: vc)
}
}


error message - "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

Comment: Because when you are accessing it, it hasn't called `viewDidLoad()` yet. So the value is not set. Put a print in `viewDidLoad()` and you'll see if it's printed or not.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that `getFrames` is a static method and that you are working with a local ViewController instance that you create inside the function and since the properties you have a problem with are set inside `viewDidLoad` which hasn't been called for the local object you get a crash.

My impression of your code is that you want use the view controller object that is a class property so I suggest you make the function an instance method and use the property `vc`, that is set in `init(viewController:)`,  instead

```
func getFrames(forRow row: Int, forColoumn col: Int) -> CGRect{
    print(vc.SPACE_FROM_TOP_EDGE)
    print(vc.TILE_SIZE)
    let x =   (CGFloat(col) * 40.0)
    let y =  vc.SPACE_FROM_TOP_EDGE! + (CGFloat(row) * 40.0)

    return CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), size: CGSize(width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
}
```